# Parse from JSON response

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, ios7.1

I am getting the JSON response

```
(
        {
        Response = success;
        UserId = 287;
    }
)
```

I tried to parse the user id with below code

```
NSDictionary *dataDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:receivedData options:0 error:&e];
    NSLog(@"%@", dataDictionary);
    NSString *useridstring=[dataDictionary valueForKey:@"UserId"];
```

But am getting the user id `( 287 )`.
Please suggest me that how to get user id without paraparentheses

Comment: Why are you treating `useridstring` as a string?  In your response, it's an integer.  Also, that response simply isn't JSON.  Have you perhaps included the printed output rather than the actual JSON?

Comment: i am getting parantheses even for parsing integer also. here i need to get  the  data without parantheses

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your response is not a dictionary, it's an array. So your code should look like this:

```
NSArray *dataArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:receivedData options:0 error:&e];
NSLog(@"%@", dataArray);
NSDictionary *dataDictionary = dataArray[0]; //Same as objectAtIndex:
NSString *userIDString = dataDictionary[@"UserID"]; //Same as objectForKey:
//If you're still getting parens try this:
//int userIDInt = [dataDictionary[@"UserID"] intValue];
```

Comment: @iOSDeveloper how can you get parentheses in an int?

Comment: that thing i dont know but even after trying your code also no change

Comment: @iOSDeveloper Well it's impossible. Please show the code where you print out the int.

Comment: ya sure, give me few minutes

Comment: thank you rmilo i got it with this code  *** NSString *userId=[jsonArr1.firstObject valueForKey:@"UserId"]; ***

Answer (score 1):

You need to fetch integer value from your JSON response.

```
int userid = [[dataDictionary valueForKey:@"UserId"] intValue];
```

If getting parentheses in integer response too, then it is problem with `JSON` response recived. for a workaround you can use -

```
NSString *useridstring=[dataDictionary valueForKey:@"UserId"];
int userid = [[useridstring substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(1, useridstring.length - 2)] intValue]
```

EDIT --

You are getting an array in response, for this you have to use -

```
int userid = [[dataDictionary valueForKey:@"UserId"] firstObject];
```

Comment: i am getting parantheses even for parsing integer also. here i need to get the data without parantheses

Comment: -[__NSArrayI length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xfe79e10  program is terminating with this error

Comment: @iOSDeveloper so it means its not even a string, its an array in the response. which is causing you issue. Check edited answer again.

Comment: thanks for your support , i got answer now i used *** NSString *userId=[jsonArr1.firstObject valueForKey:@"UserId"]; ***